# Rich Editor with images browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What are the options out there to have a rich editor that is integrated with images browser working with amazon s3?

I need to people to edit, upload images, use images by browsing into their uploaded images.
Is there a ready to go gem that can do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin for Ckediotor :

http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst4033_Amazon-S3-File-Manager-for-TinyMCE-and-CKEditor.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Isn't there a gem that do the job? a live repo on github? as we rails 4 is coming, plugins is not recommended, right?

Comment: This plugin is for Ckeditor, not for rails. You can put files to /vendor/assets directory. Also Ckeditor is available  via gem - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: do you mean that its not related to rails any way?

Comment: It's related to rails because you're using rails. But expecting a gem for any plugin for popular rich text editor is useless